# Windows 7 - delete all files+empty folders with with specific extension recursively

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have tried to follow the advice here:
[Need to delete all the files with one extension on a drive in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/178188/need-to-delete-all-the-files-with-one-extension-on-a-drive-in-windows-7)

But if I want to delete all files in a specific folder, with a specific extension, that doesn't work.

I have a folder with `*.ASP` and `*.ASPX` files, and I need to delete all the `*.ASP` files but keep the ASPX pages.

I also need to delete a folder if it is empty, after deleting the file(s).

How would I delete all the ASP pages easily, including empty folders? Command prompt is no problem.

EDIT: This is the trick in PowerShell:

```
Get-ChildItem -path . -recurse -include *.asp | 
  Where-Object {-not $_.PSIsContainer} |
  Remove-Item -Verbose
```

Comment: some other solutions: https://superuser.com/q/238900/241386

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove all files with a specific extension can be done with something like:

`cd C:\ path\to\directory\extension`

`del /s *.extension`

For removing empty folders I would suggest looking at a question from stackoverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831286/how-to-delete-empty-folders-using-windows-command-prompt

EDIT: Obviously I suggest caution running this sort of command on an entire drive. There might be something you need. So do be careful.

Comment: That doesn't delete it recursively, does it?

Comment: My apologies. /s will do that for you. You can also include /p for a prompt on each file if you really wish.

Comment: This removes both *.ASP and *.ASPX in my end :-)

Comment: Seems to be a problem with old DOS commands. Seems you can do something with PowerShell, but I don't have much knowledge of this. There appears to be a good answer from serverfault: http://serverfault.com/questions/42856/delete-just-asp-files

Comment: Works great. Use `del /s /p *.extension` if you want a prompt for confirmation for each file deletion.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way to do it with [JP Software's TCC/LE](http://jpsoft.com/tccledes.htm):

```
del /s /x *.asp
```

The `/s` option causes recursion into subdirectories, and the `/x` option causes emptied directories to be removed.

TCC will not match short filenames with the `*.asp` wildcard.  That sort of wildcard matching is a non-default feature that has to be turned on.  The wildcard will just match long filenames, so the problem caused by `*.aspx` files happening to have `*.asp` short filenames will not occur.

### Further reading

- JP Software. [*DEL*](http://jpsoft.com/help/del.htm).  Take Command / TCC Help.
- JP Software. [*LFN Searches*](http://jpsoft.com/help/lfnsearch.htm).  Take Command / TCC Help.